# Count items in column SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table that looks like,

```
id
2
2
3
4
5
5
5
```

How do I get something like,

```
id count
 2  2
 3  1
 4  1
 5  3
```

where the `count` column is just the count of each id in the `id` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the GROUP BY operation

```
 SELECT id, COUNT(id)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, count(id) from table_name group by id
```

or

```
select id, count(*) from table_name group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

What GROUP BY clause does is this:

It will split your table based on ids i.e all your 1's are separated, then the 2's , 3's and so on. You can assume it like new tables are created where in one table all the 1's are stored, 2's in another , 3's in yet another and so on.
Then after that the SELECT query is applied on each of these separate tables and the result is returned for each of these "groups".
Good luck!
Kudos! :)